# Django installation with python

Tags: django, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, osx-mavericks

My intent is to create a project in Django for which I installed pip,virtualenv and django packages. Python was installed my default on my OS X mavericks. The location for python is /usr/bin whereeas the packages I installed using pip (and including pip) werr by default installed into /usr/local/bin. 
A post I read advises that these paths for python,virtualenv and pip should be the same(/usr/local/bin). I dnt have that going for me. I also checked my ~ directory and I dont see any .bash_profile file available with any PATH variable set.

Do I have to ensure that these paths are the same because I cannot seem to move python istall to /usr/local/bin where all my packages reside.

Comment: (1) Install python, (2) install pip, (3) install virtualenv, (4) make a virtualenv anywhere using `mkvirtualenv`, (5) activate the virtual env you just created, (6) pip install django. Done!

Comment: "A post you read"? You should avoid taking advice from random posts on the Internet (and yes, that includes SO answers).

Comment: Thankyou rnevius. 
Point noted, Daniel Roseman.